# Parameter pack list expansion causes variadic constructor overload to fail

Tags: c++

I have a struct with two variadic constructors, distinguished by the presence of a single `int const*` argument at the front of the second one:

```
struct S
{
    template<class... Args> S(Args... args)
    {
        int arr[sizeof...(args)] = { args... }; // [A]
    }
    template<class... Args> S(int const *p, Args... args) {} // [B]
};

int main()
{   
    int i = 1;
    S s(&i, 1, 2); // [C]
    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual C++ 2015, line [A] causes: `error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int'`. If I comment out line [A] then it compiles fine and [C] calls [B], so it seems the presence of the initializer list causes the compiler to look inside the function and get greedy to try convert all argumenargs to `int`, ignoring interpretation [B].

If I keep [A] but change the constructor call in [C] to `S s((int const*)&i, 1, 2);` then it also compiles ok, so [A] seems to prevent the implicit conversion from `int*` to `int const*` which usually works for regular functions.

If I don't want to explicitly const cast the pointer in all my constructor calls, instead of line [A] I could use a recursive function to unpack the parameter pack into an int array, but that's more messy. The simplest solution is just to change [B] to `template<class... Args> S(int *p, Args... args) {}`, but then that hides my intention for `*p` not to be changed.

Comment: Are you allowed to make `int i` a `constexpr int i`?

Comment: I could change this example to `int const i = 1` and it works but in general no I am not always passing the address of an `int const`, usually I'm passing an array.

Answer (score 1):

The reason [A] is chosen is because the parameter pack can exactly match `int*`, so no const conversion is needed to get to [B].

One option is to use an overloaded helper to simply provide a "value-getter"  that you can call on the parameter pack:

```
int get_value_impl(int _in)
{
   return _in;
}

int get_value_impl(const int* _in)
{
   return *_in;
}


struct S
{
    template<class... Args> S(Args... args)
    {
        int arr[sizeof...(args)] = { get_value_impl(args)... }; // [A]
    }
};

int main()
{   
    int i = 1;
    S s(&i, 1, 2); // [C]
    return 0;
}
```

And now you don't need [B] at all.

If you have more types, you can add more overloads to `get_value_impl`, and you'll preserve the structure of `S`. If things get more complicated than this, you may want to consider using SFINAE to select an implementation of `get_value_impl`. I think of this solution as a simpler tag dispatch. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4035f674449198ef)

Comment: Sorry my example wasn't very clear, I actually want different behavior for [B]. Normally when I call [B] I am passing an int array as the first argument and it's a bunch of data which I want treated separately from the rest of the args which are just int values. I see that the parameter pack can match the `int*` but I don't think that is the reason [B] is ignored, because if you comment out line [A] (just the line, leave the enclosing function) then [B] does get called. So somehow it is the presence of the initializer list on line [A] which causes the compiler to ignore [B].

Comment: @GeorgeSkelton: That if you commented out the line it would call [B] is false. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3113521352df1ad8). It calls A for the reason I stated, which is exact type matching in the parameter list. If you really want [B] to get called, then you need to make [A] a worse candidate, which you can do with tag dispatch or SFINAE.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading variadic templates can get pretty nightmarish. One option would be to add an overload which takes an `int*` and delegates to the `int const*` constructor:

```
template<class... Args> S(int *p, Args... args) : 
    S(static_cast<int const*>(p), args...) { }
```

You might want to think about perfect-forwarding `args` in that case if you're going to be passing large classes around.

Comment: Agreed that works but then it's not clear to the user which one is getting called and whether their data `*p` is protected. I need to look into perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it picks your first constructor, not the second one. The reason is, that `&i`  binds to a reference of `int* const`.

What you can do is use type_traits to select the ctor, like this (C++14):

```
template<typename First, typename ...Args> 
S(T && t, Args && ...args) : 
       S(  std::is_same<int,std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv<T>>>(), 
           std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

template<typename ...Args>
S(std::false_type, int* const p, Args&&...args) //[A]

template<typename ...Args>
S(std::true_type, Args&&...args) //[B]
```

Comment: Missing 2nd argument of `is_same`.